# What will happen if you change one of the fermions in NSR superstring action to be purely imaginary?

Tags: string-theory, fermions

In the NSR superstring action, we always have the spinor with two components $\psi_{\pm}^{\mu}$. In books, this spinor is always taken to be Majorana, so that $\psi_{\pm}^{\mu^*} = \psi_{\pm}^\mu$. My question is can we have a theory where one of these fermion components is real while the other one is purely imaginary, say,
$\psi_{\pm}^* = \pm\psi_{\pm}$. I understand in this case one might not be able to use the Majorana representation of Dirac gamma matrices in 2d, but it seems that equations of motion won't change. Can someone shed some light on this matter, or suggest some references to clear this up? Thanks.

Comment: This can change the behavior of things like time reversal symmetry, because you may be changing which real Clifford algebra you're working with. Check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_Clifford_algebras#Real_case

Comment: Well thats true. But seems having one hermitian and one anti-hermitian mode on L/R makes things quite complicated.

Comment: They always appear together in a Hermitian combination like $i \gamma_1 \gamma_2$ though.